# Converting .iso to .img in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, conversion, iso-image, hdiutil

I'm trying to convert an .iso file (Ubuntu disc image) to a .img file.

I run a command like so:

`hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu.img ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso`

But no matter what, I get the error: `hdiutil: convert failed - not recognized`

I'm not sure how to resolve this problem or how else I can convert. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure the iso is not corrupt?  Are you able to mount the iso?

Comment: Works for me. I second @h0tw1r3's suspicion that the iso file is broken.

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem while trying to create an Ubuntu Server USB disk from a downloaded .iso file.  Taking h0tw1r3's advice, I ran `md5 ~/path/to/ubuntu-server.iso` and it came back with a different value than the one found on the [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) wiki page, indicating that my download was a "corrupted" .iso file.

To fix it, I opened the .torrent file from the [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) page in Transmission, which automatically scanned the corrupt file in my Downloads folder, figured out what I was missing, and corrected the file by downloading only those parts.  Three cheers for bittorrent!

Comment: +1 for mentioning the use of BitTorrent in only re-downloading the broken parts of the file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and even ran md5 check which was successful, 
the problem was the order of the parameters in the command.

Try this:

```
hdiutil convert ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso -format UDRW -o ubuntu.img
```